# VBA: Paste excel range to powerpoint placeholder without using .Select

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I want to paste a named excel range to a content placeholder in powerpoint in a custom layout. I'm currently using code like this

```
ranger.Copy
currentPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide ppt.slides.Count
activeSlide.shapes("Picture").Select msoTrue
ppt.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
```

It usually works but sometimes fails inexplicably. I have seen elsewhere on this site, [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169905/resizing-picture-using-powerpoint-vba), saying to avoid using .Select method. Instead use something like

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)
```

However, I can't figure out how to use the second method to copy straight to a content placeholder. Is that possible?

Edit, regarding Shai's suggestion. Current code is

```
For ii = activeSlide.shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
If activeSlide.shapes.Item(ii).Name = "Picture" Then
    shapeInd = ii
    Exit For
End If
Next ii

Set oSh = activeSlide.shapes.PasteSpecial(2, msoFalse)(shapeInd)
```

The "Picture" shape is a "Content" Placeholder. The other two shapes are text boxes.

Comment: take a look at my answer and code below, let me know if it works as you intended

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do as you mentioned in your post.

First it creates all the necessary PowerPoint objects, including setting the Presentation and `PPSlide`.

Afterwards, it loops through all `Shapes` in `PPSlide`, and when it finds the `Shape` with `Name = "Picture"` it retrieves the index of the shape in that sheet, so it can Paste the `Range` object directly to this Shape (as Placeholder).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExporttoPPT()

Dim ranger          As Range
Dim PPApp           As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres          As Presentation
Dim PPSlide         As Slide
Dim oSh             As Object

Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations("PPT_TEST") ' <-- change to your open Presentation
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(9)

Set ranger = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5")    
ranger.Copy

Dim i As Long, ShapeInd As Long

' loop through all shapes in Slide, check for Shape Name = "Picture"
For i = PPSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If PPSlide.Shapes.Item(i).Name = "Picture" Then
        ShapeInd = i '<-- retrieve the index of the searched shape
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Set oSh = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(2, msoFalse)(ShapeInd) ' ppPasteEnhancedMetafile = 2

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the very last line.

ShapeRange.Item : Integer out of range. 2 is not in Index's valid range of 1 to 1.

I'm not sure why that's happening. I've verified that activeSlide.shapes.Count is 3

Comment: @drj3122 which line ? how many shapes do you have in Slide 9 ? does `ShapeInd` has a value ? can you try in debug mode ?

Comment: `Set oSh = activeSlide.shapes.PasteSpecial(2, msoFalse)(shapeInd)`

3 shapes on the slide. `shapeInd` is the proper value (2)

Comment: @drj3122 is `oSh` defined `As Object` ? or `As Shape` ?

Comment: defined `As Object`

Comment: @drj3122 what type of `Shapes` you have in slide 9 ? What type is `"Picture"` ? I'm scratching my head, since it's working nicely on my PowerPoint, and I'm trying to know the difference

Comment: I added my current code to my question. I'm using powerpoint 2010. Maybe its a version issue.